# how can we prove that this function is homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G_1 , ... , G_n$ are groups 
let $G=G_1\times G_2\times\dotsb\times G_n$.

$E_p\colon G\to G_{p^{-1}(1)}\times G_{p^{-1}(2)}\times\dotsb\times G_{p^{-1}(n)}$
where $p \in S_n$ is defined as 
$(g_1 , g_2 , \dotsc , g_n )\mapsto(g_{p^{-1}(1)} , g_{p^{-1}(2)} , \dotsc ,g_{p^{-1}(n)})$.

Now in the case $G_1 = G_2 = \dotsb = G_n$, show that the function $A\colon S_n\to\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ defined by $p\mapsto E_p$ is homomorphism.

I tried to solve it "the idea is not difficult" but every time, I found it's not a homomorphism!

So I need help

thanx

This is an exercise #8 in Dummit and Foote's abstract algebra book 
page 156 but i have changed the symbols because I can't use the greek symbols in this site.

Comment: Some $\LaTeX$ tips: you don't have to put dollar signs around each individual symbol - if you want a number of symbols in a row you can just put one dollar sign at the start and another at the end. For greek letters, just type the name of the letter proceeded by a backslash between dollars. For example, \zeta (between dollars) produces $\zeta$.

Comment: Could you put in some of the calculations showing it is not a homomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute. Let $\sigma, \tau\in S_n$ and $g = (g_1, \ldots, g_n) \in G$, then 
we have denoting by $()_i\colon G \to G_i$ the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate:
\begin{align*} (E_\sigma E_\tau g)_i &= (E_\tau g)_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}\\
  &= g_{\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}(i)}\\
  &= g_{(\sigma\tau)^{-1}(i)}\\
  &= (E_{\sigma\tau}g)_i 
\end{align*}
Hence $E_\sigma E_\tau = E_{\sigma\tau}$, as wished.

Comment: plz check the answer by celtschk , because his way is the way i followed .

Comment: @MathsLover Please check my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand,

$E_{p_1p_2}(g_1,\ldots,g_n) = (g_{(p_1p_2)^{-1}(1)},\ldots,g_{(p_1p_2)^{-1}(n)})=(g_{p_2^{-1}(p_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,g_{p_2^{-1}(p_1^{-1}(n))})$

On the other hand,

$E_{p_1}(E_{p_2}(g_1,\ldots,g_n)) = E_{p_1}(g_{p_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,g_{p_2^{-1}(n)})$

Now define $g'_n:=g_{p_1^{-1}(n)}$. Then we have

$E_{p_1}(E_{p_2}(g_1,\ldots,g_n)) = E_{p_1}(g'_1,\ldots,g'_n) = (g'_{p_1^{-1}(1)},\ldots,g'_{p_1^{-1}(n)}) = (g_{p_2^{-1}(p_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,g_{p_2^{-1}(p_1^{-1}(n))})$

So we get $E_{p_1p_2}=E_{p_1}E_{p_2}$.

Comment: this is what made me confused !!

Comment: The problem here is, that the $i$-th component of, say, $E_{p_1}(h_1, \ldots, h_n)$ is $h_{p_1^{-1}(i)}$, right? So to compute $E_{p_1}(g_{p_2^{-1}(1)}, \ldots, g_{p_2^{-1}(n)})$, we have $h_j = g_{p_2^{-1}(j)}$ for each $j$, that is $h_{p_1^{-1}(i)} = g_{p_2^{-1}(p_1^{-1}(i))}$ and not the other way round.

Comment: @martini: Actually I now figured it out myself just when your comment appeared. I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: @martini , thanx ! great answer . but let me ask , why is the other way wrong ? i mean , we know that $ToM(i) = T(M(i))$ where $T,M$ $\in S_n $ , when we use this rule with the definition of $E_p$ we get the wrong way ! so why is this rule wrong here ? why can't we use it ?